# IOS clickable circle UIButton that don't fire touch events in it's corners

Tags: uibutton, rounded-corners, touch-event

http://postimg.org/image/jasludl81/   <---link to a sample image

Hi All. I just started to learn IOS programming, so please be kind. :) Here's my dilemma:

I need a control that fires touchDown, touchUpInside, touchUpOutside and touchDragEnter events. So a UIButton seems to be the most logical element to accomplish this, right? I also need the buttons to be in a shape of a circle and can be placed on top of each other.

I have accomplished the first requirement: have them of in a shape of a circle. The issue now is: since a button is rectangular by default, the corners can still fire the touch events. This would be fine if a button is on the canvas on its own. But, if a circle button is on top of another, touch events fire the wrong event when a user taps close enough to the corner of the topmost button.

Question: How can I avoid this situation? What alternative do I have if this issue can't be fixed using a UIButton? If I use another control, it needs to have support for the touch events mentioned above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: a couple questions here:  1) why do you want to fire so many events when the button is touched?  shouldn't just a "touchDown" do the job?  2) do you want touch events in the corners or do you really only want them enabled for the exact circle sizes?

Comment: Hi Michael, 1) imagine i have 2 buttons side by side (A) and (B), if i touchDown on A it executes (let's say) routineA1. Now, if i touchDown on B and keep my fingers on B while also doing a touchDown on A, A should execute routineA2. I need the touchUps to update a kind of variable to know if the user is still holding on to B. Something like: TouchDownEventForButtonA : IF(BUTTON-B is on a press-state) THEN executeRoutineA1 ELSE executeRoutineA2 ENDIF.

Comment: Michael, for number 2) I only want the touchdown to fire within the bounderies of the circles, Not its corners. Thanks in advance.